# downloading a Text Editor problem for visual studio

Tags: asp.net, text-editor

I’m faced with an usual problem. Currently, I’m working on a site as a hobby and I want to use a text editor. The problem is I do all my work from school. Unfortunately the school uses a drive shield on all their computers. So every time you turn off the computer it wipes the hard drive clean and uses an image of the original operating system once booted up. With this said –  could I still download a text editor and have it working for visual studio without too much trouble? Thanks for your time.

Paul

Comment: Wait...are you trying to use a Text Editor or are you trying to use Visual Studio. I'm a tad confused. If you're using Visual Studio...what do you need the text editor for?

Comment: Visual Studio is a text editor, in addition to lots of other things. Why are you downloading something 'for it?'

Comment: I'm trying to add something like a rich text editor for visual studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are restoring an image, you can't do it.  Essentially, they are blowing away any changes the students make to the machines.  I would either 1) ask them to add the text editor to the image or 2) bring in a usb flash drive with the editor installed on the key drive.

I'm *assuming* you are using Visual Studio but editing text in a separate program (such as VIM - the best text editor in the world).  Otherwise, just use Visual Studio directly.  It's awesome enough unless you use ViEmu to embed VI-bindings inside VS.  :^)

Comment: My problem is I want to store documents in my DB and when I display these documents I want tabs and line breaks. I've been experimenting using REGEX to detect line breaks and tabs and replace it with a special character but when I go to paste a document into my text-box - all the tabs are automatically eliminated

Comment: How are you storing your "document"?  Are you preserving the exact representation of the document in the DB or are you just streaming clear text?